# Google pub/sub stops sending messages

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using the latest version google-cloud-pubsub and am experiencing a bug that has been claimed to be fixed.

I am using this version and the code example in there: https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-pubsub/

```
<snip>
subscription = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_name)
def callback(message):
   print(message.data)
   message.ack()
subscription.open(callback)
<snip>
```

Problem: So, after about 4-5hrs of me running the subscriber worker that calls the subscriber, it stops receiving messages.

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there were messages being published in your backlog? Also are you waiting afterwards for the subscriber to complete? Replacing `subscription.open(callback)`  with `subscription.open(callback).result` will cause you to wait on the future so that the program does not return. Providing more of your code may make this easier to debug.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the messages were being posted. I found out that the problem was because I was running 2 multiprocess functions in the background when I saw a matching message(in callback). I also saw another thread by a person who rant into similar issue.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I'm using Pub/sub in multiprocess from django webapp. Any resolution? In my case, it stops listening after a few days until I restart the server.